# WSO2: How can i get user Information with API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

i would have some information about Users.
I use this Scim API https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users

ìThe response is missing some information such as **account disabled**.
Can i retrive this information somehow?

(Maybe i need to use the claims in some way)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but with the following SCIM api you can find more information about the desired user: "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/user/v1.0/pi-info/<Base64&URLEncoded_username>"

Here is the link for the API: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#UserExport#getUserById

Additionally you can extend SCIM user information as the following links explain:
[1]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#extending-the-scim-20-api
[2]https://everything1know.wordpress.com/2018/09/17/user-account-locking-with-scim-api-in-wso2-identity-server-5-4-0/

You can configure there your desired claims similarly to the "accountLocked" attribute explained in those links.